# How do I clear cached SSL state data from schannel?

Tags: windows, ssl, cache, outlook

I'm trying to [clear SSL state data for a normal TLS session](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40179/396) (no client certs are involved) for Outlook when connecting to a SSL based CAS server.

How do I clear the SSL state of SChannel?

Does the following command completely clear that state?

```
 certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now
```